# code igniter active records - help streamlining process

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, memory

I am currently using the below code to get a list of uuid's then split them into groups of 1000, then insert those groups into the database.

This works fine except this has to work on at times, over a million uuid's
The issue is this uses a massive amount of memory, so I need help to streamline this process to use less memory...

```
public function send_daily_email($dealId) {
  set_time_limit(0);
  $deal = $this->ci->deal->get($dealId);
  if ($deal == false)
    throw new exception('Unknown Deal Specified');

  $users = $this->db->select('uuid')->from('userRegionLink')->where('regionId', $deal->region)->get();

  if ($users->num_rows() == 0)
    throw new exception('No users in region');

  $message = $this->ci->load->view('emails/daily', array('name' => $deal->title, 'content' => $deal->snippet), true);
  $uuids = array();

  foreach ($users->result() as $u)
    $uuids[] = $u->uuid;

  $uuids = array_chunk($uuids, 1000);

  $sendId = 0;
  foreach ($uuids as $batch) {
    $count = count($batch);
    $this->db->set('dealId', $dealId)->set('content', $message)->set('regionId', $deal->region)->set('recipients', $count)->set('created', 'NOW()', false)->set('status', 'Creating');
    if ($sendId === 0) {
      $this->db->insert('dealEmailParent');
      $sendId = $this->db->insert_id();
      $this->db->set('sendId', $sendId)->where('id', $sendId)->update('dealEmailParent');
    }
    else
      $this->db->set('sendId', $sendId)->insert('dealEmailParent');

    $insert = array();

    foreach ($batch as $uuid)
      $insert[] = array('parentId' => $sendId, 'uuid' => $uuid);

    $this->db->insert_batch('dealEmailChild', $insert);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reworking can insert 1,000,000 "users" in under a minute without any memory limits :)

```
public function create_daily_email($dealId)
    {
        $time_start = microtime(true);
        set_time_limit(0);
        $deal = $this->ci->deal->get($dealId);
        if ($deal == false)
            throw new exception('Unknown Deal Specified');


        $message = $this->ci->load->view('emails/daily', array('name' => $deal->title, 'content' => $deal->snippet), true);

        $start = 0;
        $end = 50000;

        $q = $this->db->select('uuid')->from('userRegionLink')->where('regionId', $deal->region)->limit($end, $start)->get();
        $sendId = 0;

        while ($q->num_rows() != 0) {

            //do stuff

            $uuids = array();

            foreach ($q->result() as $u)
                $uuids[] = $u->uuid;

            $uuids = array_chunk($uuids, 1000);

            foreach ($uuids as $batch) {
                $count = count($batch);
                $this->db->set('dealId', $dealId)->set('content', $message)->set('regionId', $deal->region)->set('recipients', $count)->set('created', 'NOW()', false)->set('status', 'Creating');
                if ($sendId === 0) {
                    $this->db->insert('dealEmailParent');
                    $sendId = $this->db->insert_id();
                    $this->db->set('sendId', $sendId)->where('id', $sendId)->update('dealEmailParent');
                    $parentId = $sendId;
                }
                else {
                    $this->db->set('sendId', $sendId)->insert('dealEmailParent');
                    $parentId = $this->db->insert_id();
                }

                $insert = array();

                foreach ($batch as $uuid) {
                    $insert[] = array(
                        'parentId' => $parentId,
                        'uuid' => $uuid
                    );
                }

                $this->db->insert_batch('dealEmailChild', $insert);
            }

            //stop stuff

            unset($q);
            unset($uuids);
            unset($insert);
            $start = $start + $end;
            $q = $this->db->select('uuid')->from('userRegionLink')->where('regionId', $deal->region)->limit($end, $start)->get();
        }

        $this->db->set('status', 'Pending')->where('sendId', $sendId)->update('dealEmailParent');

        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $time = $time_end - $time_start;

        die("Did nothing in $time seconds");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say this, but from what I know about CodeIgniter, the only way it knows to fetch results is to fetch the *entire* resultset at once, even if you only need one row, or even if you want to fetch a row at a time and do some processing.  It doesn't operate with cursors as the native mysql(i)/PDO functionality does.

For this large a dataset, I'd suggest sticking to the native PHP database functions and foregoing CodeIgniter's active record database classes.

Comment: I should say that it does have functions to fetch just a single row, but the main result and result_array functions generate the entire resultset every time.